# Connections between the solution of simple ordinary equation, normal distribution and heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, intuition, heat-equation, connections

The solution to the following simple first-order linear ordinary differential equation:

$$x'=-tx, x(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

is the [Standard normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)!

One solution to another famous (partial) differential equation, the heat equation, is - given the right conditions - also the normal distribution. This is far from being a coincidence (see e.g. [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780817648022-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-791408-p173900821&ei=PGutVPa3A8XVarCdgZgH&usg=AFQjCNEzTVWyrnq9F_dBxMXCJXjFxdq3MA&sig2=F-oxxoWZfqh79EAbbC9j-Q&bvm=bv.83134100,d.d2s&cad=rjt) and many more).

**My question**

Does this mean anything? Is there an intuition why this is the case or is this just a coincidence? Or are there any deeper connections between the above ordinary differential equation, the heat equation and the normal distribution?

**Edit:**
I asked a question concerning the physical interpretation of the right hand side of the equation here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158425/which-physical-entities-equal-distance-times-time

This is also the reason why I changed the original notation to $t$ and $x(t)$ because I think it could give a better physical intuition to think in terms of time, distance and velocity.

Comment: It's not an intuition of course, but if you want to find special class of solutions to heat equation called "automodel solution" then you obtain an ODE instead of PDE. After simplification you obtain exactly the same ODE as you stated above. So that's the part of connection.

Comment: @Evgeny: This sounds very promising - could you formulate an answer? Thank you :-)

Comment: I haven't found good reference for this, so in my critical opinion I'm not ready to suggest this as an answer :)

Comment: You do release that the physics of the diffusion equation is that of Brownian motion right?

Comment: @Chinny84: I do, but I don't see the connection between this pde/ the normal distribution and the above simple ode.

Comment: is there a reason why the differential equation must be first order?

Comment: @abel: No, not necessarily, but see answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100063/346

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ODE can be expressed as $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\log x)=-t$, which readily implies that $\log x$ is a downward parabola, or $x\propto\exp(-\frac12t^2)$. But that's not very illuminating.

---

As we know, the normal distribution is the limit of the binomial distribution for large $n$. The probability mass function of the binomial distribution, taking $p=q=\frac12$, is
$$f(k)=\binom nk 2^{-n},$$
so the "slope" is
$$f(k+1)-f(k)=\left(\frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)}-1\right)f(k)=\left(\frac{n-k}{k+1}-1\right)f(k)=\frac{n-2k-1}{k+1}f(k).$$
Expressing $k$ relative to the location of the peak via $k=n/2+\ell$, and taking $n\gg1$, we have
$$f(k+1)-f(k)\approx-\frac{2\ell+1}{n/2}f(k),$$
that is, the "slope" is roughly proportional to $-\ell f(k)$. One can expect that after suitable limits and scaling this will reduce to
$$f'(t)\propto -tf(t).$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. What do you think about this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100063/346

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it makes much sense. You could apply the same argument to any other symmetrical, unimodal distribution and conclude that it should also satisfy $y' = -xy$.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I understand that but doesn't it show that the normal distribution is the simplest and in a way most natural unimodal distribution?

Comment: If that's all you want to show, then sure (for a *particular* notion of "simplest"). But that's not the same as showing how it's connected to the central limit theorem and the heat equation, which is what your original question is about.

Comment: Do you see a connection between the heat equation and the above ode? Both have the normal distribution as a solution, is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

From a physical point of view, the connection between the heat equation and the normal distribution is clear, because the heat equation can be derived by considering Brownian motion.

Brownian motion means adding up lots of independent, identically distributed numbers - each time a particle moves, we assume it moves a random amount, with each of these being drawn independently from the same distribution. Thus if the particle has moved $n$ times, we have to add up $n$ such numbers to find its position. The [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) tells us that as $n$ approaches infinity, the sum of $n$ such random numbers will approach a Gaussian distribution. So if we start with a whole load of particles all in the same place (more or less), and we let them diffuse for a long enough time, the result will be approximately a normal distribution.

As for the relationship to your equation, I'm not sure. I mean, obviously they're related in that $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}$ is a solution, and I can see various intuitive ways to see that this should indeed be a solution to both equations. But it seems like there should be something deeper and more 'physical' than that, and I can't for the moment see what it is.

Comment: "it seems like there should be something deeper and more 'physical' than that" - I feel the same way! Thank you

Comment: What do you think about this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100063/346 ?

Answer (score 2):

Using a self-similar solution which is
$$
\partial_t T = \nu\partial_{xx}T
$$
we can look at self similar transform via
$$
\frac{\bar{T}}{t}\sim \nu\frac{\bar{T}}{x^2}\implies x\sim (\nu t)^{1/2} 
$$
using a transform of the form
$$
\zeta = \dfrac{x}{(\nu t)^{1/2} }
$$
then lets look for solutions of the form
$$
T = \bar{T}f(\zeta)
$$
thus we obtain
$$
\bar{T}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}\frac{d}{d\zeta}f = \nu\bar{T}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}f\tag{*}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{(\nu t)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{t}\\
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{(\nu t)^{1/2}} 
$$

thus Eq (*) becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{(\nu t)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{t}\frac{df}{d\zeta} =  \frac{1}{2} \zeta \frac{1}{t}\frac{df}{d\zeta}\\
=\nu\frac{1}{(\nu t)} \frac{d^2f}{d\zeta^2} = \frac{1}{t}\frac{d^2f}{d\zeta^2} 
$$

this leads to
$$
-\frac{\zeta}{2} f' = f''
$$
this leads to 
$$
\ln(f') = -\frac{\zeta^2}{4} + C
$$
or
$$
f' = A\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\zeta^2}{4}}
$$
and finally (well almost)
$$
f(\zeta) = A\int \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\zeta^2}{4}} d\zeta
$$
then
$$
T = \bar{T}A\int \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\zeta^2}{4}} d\zeta
$$
then you can put back the variables and then appropriate conditions yields similar to what you are asking. Since we have linked diffusion with normal distribution equation then we are done..if the above suits your question.

Comment: What do you think about this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100063/346 ?

Comment: I have had a quick look and I think I got the wrong end of the stick in this answer of mine.

Comment: Well, no, I think it is still helpful! Please keep it! It would be great if you could find the connection between the diffusion equation and the above ode :-)

Answer (score 0):

I gave it some thought and think the key for finding the connection between the above ode and the normal distribution lies in the geometric characteristics of the curve which smoothes out the form which results when you convolute the possible results of e.g. simple coin tosses.

I wrote a short teaching note about it and would appreciate feedback: [Here](http://www.h-ab.de/private-homepages/jouanne-diedrich/homepage/teaching/Teaching%20note%20-%20ode%20to%20normal%20distr.%20v1.2.pdf)

**Edit**
The connection between the pde and the ode can be seen: [here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~vvksrini/1d-fund-heat.pdf). On page 3 we see that the Cauchy problem for the diffusion equation leads naturally to the transformation of the diffusion pde into the above ode because we have to introduce a scaling factor which ensures conservation of energy through time. Compared to the separation of variables approach for the spatially bounded problem we get the additional $-t$ as a coefficient in the above equation. This leads to the additional factor $-t/2$ inside the exponential function in the solution - which creates the characteristic bell curve. Another oversimplified and intuitive way to see it is that when the line becomes spatially unbounded everything that goes up must come down to ensure a finite result, this is what the scaling factor does... which again leads to a bell-shaped solution.